# Binding a specific object of list to gridview

Tags: c#, list, uwp, datacontext

So I'm trying to print a specific object based on the ID user enter. The code below works fine if I want to print the entire list but it doesn't work if I try to print only one object.

```
this.gridView.DataContext = list.SingleOrDefault(cus => cus.cusId == ID);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try list.Where(cust => cus.cusId == ID);.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get a single object out of the collection called `list` then you should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` it's a part of `System.Linq` below is the modified code:

```
this.gridView.DataContext = list.FirstOrDefault(cus => cus.cusId == ID);
```

That being said, I don't quite understand the reason why you would set the `datacontext` of a `gridview` to a single object, but then maybe you have a `collection type` in the object for the `itemSource`